# Erro ao implementar o TensorFlow em React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-5, tensorflow

Salve! Estou tentando implementar a biblioteca [TensorFlow](https://github.com/reneweb/react-native-tensorflow#image-recognition) na minha aplicação React Native, com base [nesse](https://medium.com/@geekyants/deep-learning-with-react-native-65fae456839d) e [nesse](http://www.davifelipe.com.br/react-native-tensorflow-reconhecimento-de-imagem) tutoriais.

Porém não consigo ao menos executar o projeto, recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Unable to resolve module `../assets/graph.pb` from `C:\aplicativos\myApp\components\Index.js`: The module `../assets/graph.pb` could not be found.

O erro só ocorre por causa da extensão do arquivo (`.pb`), pois testando com arquivos de imagem no mesmo diretório tudo ocorre bem.

Tentei então a abordagem feita por [essa resposta do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51077374/5445596),
também sem resultado algum e o erro persiste.
Por último, tentei realizar a leitura do arquivo `.pb` com o [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfileassetsfilepathstring-encoding-string-promisestring), resultando em erro de alocação de memória, já que o arquivo em questão pesa mais de 80Mb.

Meu código está assim:

```
import { TfImageRecognition, TensorFlow } from 'react-native-tensorflow';

clickHandle = () => {

    const graph = require('../assets/graph.pb'); //gera erro
    const text = require('../assets/a.txt'); //gera erro

    try {
      const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
        model: graph,
        labels: text
      });

      const results = await tfImageRecognition.recognize({
        image: this.image
      });

      const resultText = `Name: ${results[0].name} - Confidence: ${results[0].confidence}`;
      this.setState({texto: resultText});

      await tfImageRecognition.close();
    } catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
 }
```

Estrutura de pastas:

```
root
|--assets
|      |_ a.txt
|      |_ graph.pb
|
|--components
|      |_ Index.js
```

**EDITADO:**

Fiz uma cópia dos arquivos para a pasta `android/app/src/main/assets` e modifiquei o código da seguinte maneira:

```
clickHandle = async () => {

    const text = {uri: 'asset:/a.txt'};
    const graph = {uri: 'asset:/graph.pb'};

    try {
      const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
        model: graph,
        labels: text
      });

      const results = await tfImageRecognition.recognize({
        image: require('../assets/YodaWhiteHouse.jpg')
      });

      const resultText = `Name: ${results[0].name} - Confidence: ${results[0].confidence}`;
      this.setState({texto: resultText});

      await tfImageRecognition.close();
    } catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
```

Resultando no erro:

[image: Could not load resource]

Comment: Tente limpar a cache com o comando `react-native start --reset-cache` e rodar o app novamente.

Comment: Mesmo erro: Could not load resource

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar o problema em questão após analisar o arquivo `ResourceManager.java` contido na pasta `node_modules\react-native-tensorflow\android\src\main\java\com\rntensorflow`.

O novo código ficou assim:

```
clickHandle = async () => {

const text = 'a.txt';
const graph = 'graph.pb';

try {
  const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
    model: graph,
    labels: text
  });

  const results = await tfImageRecognition.recognize({
    image: require('./assets/yodawhitehouse.jpg')
  });

  const resultText = `Name: ${results[0].name} - Confidence: ${results[0].confidence}`;
  this.setState({texto: resultText});

  await tfImageRecognition.close();
} catch(err) {
  alert(err);
}

}
```

com os arquivos `txt` e `pb` dentro da pasta `android/app/src/main/assets`.

Agora recebo um erro relacionado ao Graph, mas fica para uma outra pergunta, o problema dessa já foi resolvido.